# Java Split method in infinite loop confusion

Tags: java, loops, exception, split

I'm beginning a Java project where the user enters a pet shop and can either give a pet, see a list of all the pets, adopt one, or exit the shop. Since multiple pieces of information is needed in one command input, each command given by the user is split by spaces. I would think this creates an array of Strings where each word in the input is a separate element.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    while(true) {

        System.out.println("Welcome to James' Pet Shop.");
        System.out.println("Commands:\n give [type (Str)] [name (Str)] [age (in months, int)]\n list\n adopt [type (Str)] [name (Str)] [age (in months, int)]");

        String input = s.next();
        String[] inputs = input.split(" ");

        if (inputs[0].equals("give")) {



        } else if (inputs[0].equals("list")) {



        } else if (inputs[0].equals("adopt")) {

        } else if (inputs[0].equals("bye")) {

            System.out.println("Thank you for stopping bye!");
            break;

        } else {

            System.out.println("Error: please enter an appropriate command to continue");

        }

    }

}

public static void list() {

}

public static void adopt() {

}

}
```

However, when I run the code and type in more than one word (separated by spaces), it is able to test if element 0 is a certain command and follow in that conditional (i.e., if the first word is "give," "list," etc., it will follow in that path and then loop back and start over until the user says "bye"), but, say, if you were to print out the second word index 1 in the array you typed as input, it gives me the error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 at Main.main(Main.java:30). The stranger thing I found is if I bypass this error by printing instead the first word index 0 again, and I input multiple words, it will treat each element in the input as element 0, and cycle through the loop as many times as there are elements given/words typed in the input. I'm very confused...

Ex. 1

```
    String input = s.next();
    String[] inputs = input.split(" ");

    if (inputs[0].equals("give")) {

            //if you type give and another word
            //instead of printing out the latter, it gives an error
            System.out.println(input[1]);

    } else if (inputs[0].equals("list")) {
```

Ex. 2

```
    String input = s.next();
    String[] inputs = input.split(" ");

    if (inputs[0].equals("give")) {

            //instead of printing the first element and then taking more input
            //if the first word is give, and 
            //overwriting the String array inputs, it instead prints out 
            //your first word, then cycles back through and treats the 
            //subsequent words as input 0.
            //if you type "give giver", it will first print the beginning instructions,
            //then print give because it satisfies that conditional,
            //and then cycle back through the instructions and print 
            //Error: please enter an appropriate command to continue
            System.out.println(input[0]);

    } else if (inputs[0].equals("list")) {
```

Comment: Use `nextLine()` not `next()`. `next()` only scans for one token. (in this case one word)

Comment: s.next() stops reading at the first whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using the function s.next(); Over here, it returns the word only till it encounters a space. Hence, only your first command is inputted.

In order to resolve this problem, use the following code:-

```
System.out.println("Commands:\n give [type (Str)] [name (Str)] [age (in months, int)]\n list\n adopt [type (Str)] [name (Str)] [age (in months, int)]"); 
String[] inputs = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
```

This will work. Keep in mind that next() is used to input one word while nextLine() is used to input multiple words.

Comment: next() doesn't have knowledge of 'words', it recognizes a whitespace as a delimiter.